# Angularjs displaying boolean from object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have recieved object from server and trying to display its fields in table.
All fields are displaying well but boolean is always displaying as "no".

```
<tr ng-repeat="u in ctrl.users">
      <td><span ng-bind="u.id"></span></td>
      <td><span ng-bind="u.name"></span></td>
      <td><span ng-bind="u.age"></span></td>
      <td><span ng-bind="u.isAdmin ? 'yes' : 'no'"  ></span></td>
 </tr>
```

I was trying to add filter, but result was the same.

Comment: Hi. Are your sure that isAdmin is not false for all users? Try to display like this: `<td><span ng-bind="u.isAdmin"  ></span></td>` and see what you got

Comment: or maybe undefined ?

Comment: I'm sure that isAdmin is not false for all users.

Comment: When I do like this: <td><span ng-bind="u.isAdmin" ></span></td> , nothing is displayed

Comment: @Geha then it's likely not defined. Can you show us the code that defines the `isAdmin` property? Are you sure it's spelled right? Same upper/lower casing?

Comment: You need to learn how to debug your app. Print the whole object to see what is inside.

Comment: what do you get in your table if you simply use u.IsAdmin ?

Comment: @Geha It appears your object doesn't have an `isAdmin` property, so try the following to print out it's entire contents

`<pre>{{u | json}}</pre>`

Comment: @CaffGeek, when I use this  <pre>{{u | json}}</pre>  , I see that "admin" : true. I was using wrong name of property. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check you have the property name right in code.

You can print the `u` object as json with

```
<pre>{{u | json}}</pre>
```

I'm pretty sure that if the value is in the database and isn't false or null, then you have the name wrong, and it's not `isAdmin` but something else.

**EDIT:** Looks like I was right and you were using the property name `admin` instead.

Answer (score 0):

***When you return `boolean` value from ajax call you always get it as string***.
So,you need to check it like this one

```
<span ng-bind="name =='true'? 'yes' : 'no'"></span>
```

Comment: Downvoter comment please.I hope you know the exact reason

Comment: The reason is that @Geha said in a comment of its post, that the `isAdmin` property doesn't display anything. Your answer is then invalid.

Comment: @Erazihel the OP also stated originally in his question that *All fields are displaying well but boolean is always displaying as "no".* which conflicts his latter comment. I think the OP was incorrect in the comment as `u.isAdmin` be it undefined or otherwise will get evaluated as a truthy/falsy expression. To render "nothing" doesn't seem possible unless Angular is throwing an exception somewhere which wasn't mentioned.  I think the downvote is excessive.

Comment: @jusopi It doesn't conflict with the latter comment as the result would be no even if the boolean was undefined.

Comment: *All fields are displaying well but boolean is always displaying as "no".* **vs** *When I do like this: `<td><span ng-bind="u.isAdmin" ></span></td>` , nothing is displayed* **are indeed two different things**.  Please reread my comment.